# Scrolling Ads? Live scrolling widget, not random on refresh

Tags: plugins, widgets, ads

I have a current job where my client has requested to have their "sponsors" rotate in the sidebar widget. Right now I have a random ad widget which rotates them randomly...

I was wanting to know if there is a plugin or a way to make a number of image ads slide, or rotate live when you are on the page not via refresh and random.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE*** I ended up using the promo slider plugin which you can get [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/promotion-slider/) it worked great. I customized the css slightly and its easy to use and easy to set to custom sizes. Its generally made for a full size slider, I just shrunk it down to 250x375 for my ad space. You can see it live in the bottom right of this site [here](http://bcands.bc.ca/wp/).

Answer (score 0):

I looked for one of these recently, as I have seen them, but I believe they are only bundled with some commercial themes.

I ended up making one using CPT's and jQuery Tools, it was pretty simple. The steps,

1. Create a CPT with only the featured image upload ( to keep ad size to 175px x 150px in my case) and 1 meta box for the ad link url.
2. Create a function that uses  `WP_Query` to get the ads from the CPT.
3. In you're template ( or function) wrap the query function in the necessarily div class's and id's that are used by the JavaScript.

That was about it, jQuery Tools and jQuery UI both support auto-scrolling and circular looping, so no matter how many ads you have the are always showing in a seamless loop.

ps. I do have [this](https://github.com/wycks/Ad-slider/blob/master/ad-slider.php) on github as a plugin, but it is not user friendly at all, if you're a developer you might find it useful but it was written very quickly and only works for a horizontal slider.

Comment: Do you have an example of what this results in?

I cant believe there is not a plugin for this!?

Comment: No sorry, I can show you a screenshot, it auto-scrolls about 15 photos, http://imgur.com/27wqd